# How can I connect to my website database using php?

Tags: php, sql, windows

I am using this code

```
$con = mysql_connect("***.***.**.**:3306","Username","Password") or die("Error:".mysqlerror());
```

> //select database

```
mysql_select_db("DBname", $con );
```

Comment: Dude, before post quiz, please use search box to find similar quiz.

Comment: also, please learn some basics of php. you will get your answer yourself.

Comment: google is your friend https://www.google.com.au/search?q=php+connect+to+sql

Answer (score 0):

you can aslo use PHP 5 Mysqli as follows:  (OOP Style)

```
$mysqli = new mysqli ("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
    echo "ERROR";    
}

if ($mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM USERS"))
{
    echo "SUCESS";
}
```